# How to declare Abstract Class?

Tags: php, abstract-function

I am trying to make abstract method clear to me , so I wrote this code and test it. But when I run it the following error appear :

```
Fatal error: Class Book contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Book::ClassName) in C:\AppServ\www\index2.php on line 5
```

so where is the problem and why ?

```
<?php
  class Book
{
     abstract public function ClassName();
}

 class firstBook extends Book{
    public function ClassName()
    {
        echo "Called form class firstBook";
    }

}

 class secondBook extends Book{
    public function ClassName() 
    {
        echo "Called from class secondBook";
    }
}
$o = new firstBook();
$o2 = new secondBook();
$o->Classname();
$o2->Classname();
?>
```

Comment: Abstract methods are only allowed in abstract classes.

Comment: you must make class to abstract to declare function as abastract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class must also use `abstract` keyword

```
<?php
  abstract  class Book
{
     abstract public function ClassName();
}

 class firstBook extends Book{
    public function ClassName()
    {
        echo "Called form class firstBook";
    }

}

 class secondBook extends Book{
    public function ClassName() 
    {
        echo "Called from class secondBook";
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm , so what if i have to call a variable or a function from class Book ? if it became abstract i can't do that right ?

Comment: No, if you make a function ( `method` ) in `class Book` it will not become abstract. But it is good to declare all the function that you are going to use in `abstract` class and follow the contract

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare `abstract` function in a concrete class.  Update your `Book` class to be abstract.

```
abstract class Book
{
     abstract public function ClassName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You class has to be abstract.

Change

```
class Book
```

to

```
abstract class Book
```

Also, you are calling the functions wrongly.

Replace

```
$o->Classname;
$o2->Classname;
```

to

```
$o->ClassName();
$o2->ClassName();
```

### Putting it all together

```
<?php
abstract class Book
{
    abstract public function ClassName();
}

class firstBook extends Book{
    public function ClassName()
    {
        echo "Called form class firstBook";
    }

}

class secondBook extends Book{
    public function ClassName()
    {
        echo "Called from class secondBook";
    }
}
$o = new firstBook;
$o2 = new secondBook;
$o->ClassName();
$o2->ClassName();
?>
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Called form class firstBookCalled from class secondBook
```